# Adressing data.table columns based on two grep() commands in R

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to find rows based on two conditions in a data.table. These two conditions are the existence of certain words in a long string. A minimal example looks like this:

```
library("data.table")
dt <- data.table(var1 = c("abc","adb","acf"))
```

and now I try to find element 1 and 2 by looking for `"a"` and `"b"` appearing togehter in the same entry of `var1`. In reality, the data table has several hundred thousand entries and the strings are long formulas in which I look for multi-character words. Here is my attempt:

```
dt[grep("a", var1) & grep("b", var1)]
```

that throws a warning:

```
In grep("a", var1) & grep("b", var1) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

which looks like `data.table` is doing something sequentially? In my mind, this should be the same as `dt[var1 == X  & var2 == Y]` which would work... Any help is appreciated!

p.s.: For completeness here is the warning of my actual data which I hope has the same origin (otherwise my example is trash):

```
Error in `[.data.table`(collected, grep(pairs[i, 1], model_formula) &  : 
i evaluates to a logical vector length 423098 but there are 3980284 rows. 
Recycling of logical i is no longer allowed as it hides more bugs than is 
worth the rare convenience. Explicitly use rep(...,length=.N) if you 
really need to recycle.
In addition: Warning message:
In grep(pairs[i, 1], model_formula) & grep(pairs[i, 2], model_formula) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: `dt[grep("a.*b|b.*a", var1)]`

Comment: thank you so much and curse you: regular expressions! I will never get the hang of them... Could you elaborate in an answer what is happening with . and *?

Comment: also, it would be interesting to understand why my attempt doesn't work, if its not to much to ask

Comment: `a.*b|b.*a` matches either `a` followed with any 0+ chars and then `b`, or `b`, then 0+ chars and then `a`. Not quite extensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `grep` by `grepl` and it should work fine.. or adjust your regex as described in the comments.

```
dt[grepl("a", var1) & grepl("b", var1)]

#    var1
# 1:  abc
# 2:  adb
```

Answer (score 1):

A third option based on `intersect()`:

```
dt[intersect(grep("a", var1), grep("b", var1))]
```